# Get data from a form in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developed an application where user can add dynamic fields inside main form tag, so they will be able to add as many fields as they want. Now i have 2 buttons:
`Entire Form Submit` and `Dynamic form Submit`. 
Clicking on first i get entire data form, but when i click on the second i get also the same data, but i want to get just data from `<DynamicFormComponent/>`. The data what i will get clicking on the second button i want to get inside:

```js
 const onFinishDynamic = values => {
    console.log("Received values of dynamic form:", values);
  };
```

Now, the code looks like:

```js
//Main form
const MainForm = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Success:", values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = errorInfo => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{ remember: true }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your username!" }]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your password!" }]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item>
        <DynamicForm />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Entire Form Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

```js
//Dynamic Form
const DynamicForm = () => {
  const onFinishDynamic = values => {
    console.log("Received values of dynamic form:", values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "last"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Dynamic form Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
  );
};
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-silence-mub60?file=/DynamicForm.js:235-2132

Question: How to get different data clicking on the above 2 buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values, but in hooks. I have modified your components and you get the updated values on DynamicForm using basic priniciples of react.

Your **MainForm.js** looks like

```
 import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
import DynamicForm from "./DynamicForm";

const layout = {
  labelCol: { span: 8 },
  wrapperCol: { span: 16 }
};
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: { offset: 8, span: 16 }
};

const MainForm = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState({});
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Success:", values);
    setVal(values.users);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = errorInfo => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{ remember: true }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your username!" }]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your password!" }]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item>
        <DynamicForm abc={val}/>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Entire Form Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MainForm />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Your **dynamicForm.js** looks like below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Space } from "antd";
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const DynamicForm = (props) => {

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('Received values:-', props.abc)
  },[props.abc])


  return (
    <div>
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "last"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Dynamic form Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DynamicForm;
```

Comment: if i add `Form` tag i get `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>.` But if i will click on the `main submit` button i want to get the entire data from the entire form. Do you have a solution?

Comment: could you take a look please here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769208/second-value-overrides-previous-in-reactjs

Comment: I have updated the answer and you can get the value in hooks. See if its helpful to you. You can do the stuff in hook that you were trying to do on  onFinishDynamic callback

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811719/open-a-default-input-in-form-tag#62813190

Answer (score 0):

1- first of all having nested form is against the rules i think, so you should change that

2- if you want info of of some fields inside of form, you can use state to get them in an button click function

Comment: could you take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769208/second-value-overrides-previous-in-reactjs

Comment: please change question, it got issue and is closed

Comment: could you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811719/open-a-default-input-in-form-tag#62813190 . Will be great if you will help