# Open a default input in form tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next application:
https://codesandbox.io/s/uwmig?file=/index.js,

There users can add as many fields as they want and add images for each generated input, clicking on add button.

What I want to achieve is to set a default open input in my application and to get something like this:
[image]

Now the default section is open by doing:

```css
  const firstRowOpen = { name: 0, key: 0, isListField: true, fieldKey: 0 };
```

and:

```css
{fields.concat(firstRowOpen).map((field, index)... //here i map already concatinated fields and this is why appears first default block
```

Code:

```js
 <Form.List name={[fieldKey, "inner"]}>
      {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {fields.concat(firstRowOpen).map((field, index) =>
              !fieldsOnEdit.includes(index) ? (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Demo
                    idx={index}
                    upload={upload}
                    setUpload={setUpload}
                    field={field}
                  />

                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button
                      type="primary"
                      htmlType="submit"
                      key="submit"
                      onClick={() => toggleSmall(index)}
                    >
                      Toggle first row
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </Space>
              ) : (
                <Edit value={values} mode={toggleSmall} keyForm={index} />
              )
            )}

            <Form.Item>
              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => {
                  add();
                }}
                block
              >
                <PlusOutlined /> Add field to inner
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Form.List>
```

Issue: when I add an image clicking on `add` button, and after that click on `toggle first row`  button, appears another buttons bellow.

 Question: Why this issue appears? and how to solve the issue?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-ives-o81ue?file=/SubForm.js:767-2195

Comment: @Masuk Helal Anik, do you know a solution for my question? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you need to use `initialValues`

Here is an updated example of your code
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-fermi-4oedx?file=/SubForm.js

```
...
<Form
   name="dynamic_form_item"
   {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
   onFinish={onFinish}
   initialValues={{ names: [""] }}
>
...
```

Comment: i tried in my example but it does not work. Could you show in my example where should i insert  your answer?

Comment: Maybe like this? 

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-fermi-4oedx?file=/SubForm.js

Comment: in this way i get a warning: `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>.`

Comment: maybe to change the `fields` array before `map()`, but appears issues with indexes. Do you have an idea how to do?

Comment: do you have any ideas? It will be very helpful

Comment: As a temporary solution, you can write something like this.

Write this method in `SubForm.js`
`const getFields = (fields, add) => {
    if (fields.length === 0) {
      add();
      return [firstRowOpen];
    }
    return fields;
  };`

then use it in render

`getFields(fields, add).map((field, index) =>...`

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-fermi-4oedx?file=/SubForm.js

Comment: when i add for example 2 images (2 rows), and toggle the, and after that if i add additional  row, everything is broken. Do you know why?

Comment: could you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871247/increase-the-next-value-by-a-certain-number-in-relation-to-the-first-value