# Increase the next value by a certain number in relation to the first value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where user can set the time for each generated fields.

```
  const [firstTime, setFirstTime] = useState({});
  const [secondTime, setSecondTime] = useState({});

  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log(
      values.users.map(i => {
        return {
          ...i,
          time0: moment(i.time0).format("HH mm"),
          time1: moment(i.time1).format("HH mm")
        };
      })
    );
  };

  function onChange1(time, timeString, key) {
    console.log(time, timeString);
    setFirstTime({ ...firstTime, [key]: timeString });
  }
  function onChange2(time, timeString, key) {
    console.log(time, timeString);
    setSecondTime({ ...secondTime, [key]: timeString });
  }
  console.log(secondTime, firstTime);
  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    key={`item7${index}`}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    key={`item8${index}`}
                    name={[field.name, "time0"]}
                    initialValue={moment(
                      firstTime[Object.keys(firstTime)[index - 1]]|| '07:00',
                      "HH mm"
                    ).add(index * 5, "minutes")}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "time0"]}
                  >
                    <TimePicker
                      onChange={(date, dateString) =>
                        onChange1(date, dateString, field.key)
                      }
                   
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    key={`item9${index}`}
                    name={[field.name, "time1"]}
                    initialValue={moment(
                      secondTime[Object.keys(secondTime)[index - 1]] || '10:00',
                      "HH mm"
                    ).add(index * 5, "minutes")}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "time1"]}
                  >
                    <TimePicker
                      onChange={(date, dateString) =>
                        onChange2(date, dateString, field.key)
                      } 
                    />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>
```

The idea of the application is next:

1. User clicks on `add field` button where appears some inputs where user can add value
2. Th default values of date pickers is `07:00 and 10:00` (but user can change the initial values)
3. The next value of each date picker that will be generated by the user has to be higher with 5 minutes than each selected value of the user (from previous row with time pickers)

   Ex1:

   07:00  10:00 
   07:05  10:05 

   Ex2:

   User can change the first value in the next way:
   07:25  10:05
   07:30  10:10
   User can select the next values like:
   07:40  10:15
   07:45  10:20
   ...and so on..

Now the idea works only if i click on `add field` button without changing a value from date picker, and the next values will be like i  described, but appears issue when i try to change a value from a picker, because the next pickers don't take into account that the value should be higher with 5 minutes.
**Question**: How to solve the issue and to make workable the idea described above?
demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-star-nu5ld?file=/index.js:365-3725

Comment: What is your expected behaviour when suppose there are 4 fields and user goes and changes 2nd field. Should 3 and 4 field be updated automatically?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal, yes, the fields should update.

Comment: @RohanAgarwal, do you have a solution? It will be helpful

Comment: @Drew Reese, could you help?

Comment: @Rostyslav, could you take a look?

Comment: Can you share which library are you using for timepicker?

Comment: @Rohan Agarwal, ant design is the library

Comment: @Rohan Agarwal, dus you find the library?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal , did you find the library? https://ant.design/components/time-picker/

Comment: @RohanAgarwal, please, take a look in the chat. I changed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,we don't see any code here which keeps a track of your un-changed value. Also, you are adding the 5 minutes on the fly but not keeping a record of it.

To solve this, let us do all this just before you call add:

```
 <Button
     type="dashed"
     onClick={() => {
                const length = Object.keys(firstTime).length;
                if (length > 0) {
                  const newTime = moment(
                    secondTime[length - 1],
                    "HH mm"
                  )
                  const newSecTime = moment(
                    secondTime[length - 1],
                    "HH mm"
                  ).add(5, "minutes");
                  setFirstTime({ ...firstTime, [length]: newTime });
                  setSecondTime({ ...secondTime, [length]: newSecTime });
                } else {
                  setFirstTime({ ...firstTime, [length]: "07:00" });
                  setSecondTime({ ...secondTime, [length]: "10:00" });
                }
                add();
              }}
     block
     >
     <PlusOutlined /> Add field
     </Button>
```

Next lets make use of defaultValue prop of timepicker to display the value:

```
 <TimePicker
    defaultValue={moment(firstTime[index], "HH mm")}
    onChange={(date, dateString) =>
    onChange1(date, dateString, field.key)
     }
  />
```

Comment: could you take a look, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button